# Faster way of deploying compiled software

Tags: ubuntu, package, apt

I'm working on a project where I will have to deploy a large number of servers with particular software upon them. At the moment, I'm able to use the standard Ubuntu repositories, however the version of the software that is on these repos (v1.0) is considerably older than the current version available from the developers (v.1.5.6). That leaves me downloading the source, and then building locally on each server that I intend on sending out the door. It takes about an hour to build this one particular piece of software, so I got to thinking that there's a better way of doing things.

In Googling such a solution, I see that there are a number of possibilities out there, but I wanted to get SO's take on whether or not I'm going down the right path, or not. If I understand this correctly, I can create a [package](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) and then place it on either a PPA (which I believe would be publicly available) or on a private repo that I could stand up. Either option would be fine really, this isn't my software I'm merely compiling it and making it available for myself and others to use.

It's my understanding then that, as long as all my servers have the same version of Ubuntu upon them, architecture etc, I could point them to this new resource and use aptitude to install the software, without having to go through the pains (and time) of compiling.

Is this generally correct? Am I over-simplifying? Is there a better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Good question though it's a bit off-topic for StackOverflow.  https://serverfault.com/ is a better forum for this question as ServerFault covers admin and network-related questions and software release management would be a better match there.

Comment: Good point - thanks for the response, reposting on SF

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be probably to setup your own APT repository. This can be done very easily and a good explanation can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup?action=show&redirect=HowToSetupADebianRepository)

For this you also need to understand how packaging in Ubuntu works (It is pretty easy).
Then you can simply add your repository to your machines. If you deploy an update, your machines can install it with apt upgrade. Also the packages contain (in most cases) pre-compiled binaries.